# Sentry not receiving exceptions

Tags: python, django, sentry

I recently started using sentry for my Django Project. Everything was working fine in the development environment, but when i pushed it to prod, even though exception were getting thrown, but sentry wasn't reporting them on the dashboard. I tried enabling the debug setting in sentry config, and in the logs it said "Sending error event", but the event is still not being received.

Can someone help with this issue?

Python - 3.6.7
Sentry-sdk - 0.9.0

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what your dev/prod environments look like?

Comment: Which service are you using to host your application, which WSGI server do you use? Could you show an example of code that causes the Sentry event you saw in local development? Are you sure that you can reach `sentry.io` from your production environment in general?